# PHP usort() by multiple properties with a preferred value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, usort

I'm sorting following array by `price`.

```
<?php
$products = [
    [
        'state' => 'stocked',
        'price' => 1.00,
    ],
    [
        'state' => 'out-of-stock',
        'price' => 1.50,
    ],
    [
        'state' => 'unknown',
        'price' => 1.25
    ],
    [
        'state' => 'stocked',
        'price' => 1.75
    ]
];

usort($products, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['price'] <=> $b['price']; // sort by price ASC
});

var_dump($products);
```

The results works fine as expected:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["state"]=>
    string(7) "stocked"
    ["price"]=>
    float(1)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["state"]=>
    string(7) "unknown"
    ["price"]=>
    float(1.25)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["state"]=>
    string(12) "out-of-stock"
    ["price"]=>
    float(1.5)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["state"]=>
    string(7) "stocked"
    ["price"]=>
    float(1.75)
  }
}
```

---

However, I need to **prefer one state** (e.g. `stocked`) over the others, do not sort by the other states, and **then sort by price within the collection of states**.

So my desired output would be:

```
array(4) {
  [1]=> // "stocked" first, then sort by price
  array(2) {
    ["state"]=>
    string(7) "stocked"
    ["price"]=>
    float(1)
  }
  [2]=> // "stocked" first, then sort by price
  array(2) {
    ["state"]=>
    string(7) "stocked"
    ["price"]=>
    float(1.75)
  }
  [3]=> // any other state, then sort by price
  array(2) {
    ["state"]=>
    string(7) "unknown"
    ["price"]=>
    float(1.25)
  }
  [3]=> // any other state, then sort by price
  array(2) {
    ["state"]=>
    string(12) "out-of-stock"
    ["price"]=>
    float(1.5)
  }
}
```

I was able to find this set of snippets ([link](https://blog.martinhujer.cz/clever-way-to-sort-php-arrays-by-multiple-values/)) for sorting by multiple properties, but they don't take into account any preferred value, so I'm a bit lost.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of trial and error, I was able to code the right sorting algorithm:

```
usort($products, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a['state'] === 'stocked') {
        return -1;
    } elseif ($b['state'] === 'stocked') {
        return 1;
    }

    return $a['price'] <=> $b['price'];
});
```